# Can a Shaliach Tzibbur repeat Birchos HaShachar/ Korbanot for the tzibur if he had said them prior to the start of the minyan?

Tags: tefillah-betzibbur, pesukei-dezimra

If a person arrives to shul early, davens till pesikua dezimrah and is then called to start the minyan as the regular shaliach tzibbur is not around, can one lead the amud, repeat the brachot and lead the tefilla?

Can we assume karbonot are not repeated as it is generally said quietly?

Comment: What could be the problem with repeating korbanot? Just more Torah study.

Comment: What could be the basis for repeating blessings? No one needs them to be said aloud but stubborn gabbaim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discharge someone else's obligation the question would be if they are ברכת הנהנין - brachos on pleasure - which one cannot repeat if he already fulfilled his own obligation, or if they are ברכת השבח brachos of praise, which can be repeated to fullfill other's obligation.

See: Pri megadim (Aishel Avraham  46/14) who writes that by some of the brichos ha'shachar one cannot repeat them for others, since they are - ברכות הנהנין - on pleasures, and sefer Ishei Yisroel 5/(footnote 3).

However, if they are being repeated for the sake of shul decorum, [in my opinion] it would be halachiclly unnecessary and a bracha l'vatala - in vain. This should not be compared to Chazoras Ha'Shats which was instituted by chaza"l even if no one actually needs to fulfill their obligation.